# android 4.1 image reading from url

Tags: android, bitmap, android-image

Hi I am trying to get an image from `url` to `bitmap`. I have android 4.1 device. When I run this code on `new URL(). open connection().getInputStream());`  app freezes then force close. Any idea?

```
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String url = "http://netmera.com/cdn/app/file/netmera.com/series/img-48/1372262272227_89/medium";
                try {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url)
                            .openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
              }
```

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: Try with Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openStream());
Usually I'm using BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openStream(), null, BitmapOptions);

Comment: check your logcat if you have any exceptions `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: it says Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!   Error opening directory '/storage/sdcard1/', skipping: Permission denied.  @KamenStoykov I  trid it that has same problem

Comment: have you set Internet permissions in manifest or you getting NetworkOnMainTrhreadException, in those case refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9288544/2345913)

Comment: Or permission to write in External/Interl Storage ?

Comment: it has internet and storage permissions

Comment: post the stack here and you should use asyntask for network related operation

Comment: I have an async task and this runOnUiThread in this async task @Raghunandan

Comment: @user2527366 check the updated answer and post the stack trace also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running network related operation on the ui thread using `runOnUiThread`.

You should use a `Thread` or use `Asynctask`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You are probably getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Load asynctask on ui thread.

```
   new TheTask().execute().
```

AsyncTask

```
  class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
  {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String url = "http://netmera.com/cdn/app/file/netmera.com/series/img-48/1372262272227_89/medium"; 
    try {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url)
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}
}
```

Use  `runOnUiThread` to update ui and do your netowrk related operation in `doInbackground()`.

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
                 {
                  public void run() 
                  { 
                     // update ui
                  }
                 });
```

Comment: @user2527366 remove the `runonuithread` then. this    bitmap = `BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                            doctor.getPhoto()).getContent())` should be outside `runonuithread`  in `doInbackground()`. you can update ui in `runonuithread`.

Answer (score 0):

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL("your url").getContent());

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the Crash can be two things

- Network operation should not be done on the UI thread. Kindly use `AsyncTask` for this. //`NetworkOnMainThreadException`
- Do not use strong referneces for Bitmaps. Use `WeakReference<Bitmap>` objects //`OutOfMemoryException`

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it like this

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(msg.what==1){
                    doctoImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);// doctoImage you image view
                }
            }
        };

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                            doctor.getPhoto()).getContent());

                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });thread.start();
```